# Want to delete the images being added to the thumbnails when clicked on the delete link

Tags: javascript

The images are being added as thumbnails, but the code for delete operation fails to work. This is my code....
something has gone wrong in the "span.innerHtml" I know...but not able to solve it!!
The script for delete operation as DELETE as link works fine....but when integrated with the images as thumbnails it fails to work....

```
//select the files to be added
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]"/>
<output id="list"></output>

//code for delete operation(after onClick)
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('a.delete').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        imageID = $(this).closest('.image')[0].id;
        alert('Now deleting "'+imageID+'"');
        $(this).closest('.image')
            .fadeTo(300,0,function(){
                $(this)
                    .animate({width:0},200,function(){
                        $(this)
                            .remove();
                    });
            });
    });

}); 

</script>


//code to add images to thumbnails(before onClick)
<script>
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }


        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {

                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<a href="#" class="delete">Delete<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                    '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" width="110" height="150"/></a>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

</script>
```

Comment: When you say _delete_ you mean removing them from the page, right?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML _before_ and _after_ the `onClick`?

Comment: I did not get your question...is it before an after the click of the _Delete_ link?? when the image files are added, the link appears along with the image and when clicked on the link, the image has to disappear. As of now , the link appears and fails to remove the added image from the thumbnail...

Comment: Yes, exactly. To better understand what your script is doing, looking at the HTML _before_ you click the link and _after _you click the link would be useful. If the Javascript console is throwing any errors, those would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken that it was working somehow and it is not working for dynamically added images, you should change the following:

```
 $('a.delete').on('click',function(e){...
```

to

```
 $(document).on('click','a.delete', function(e){...
```

This selector is incorrect too as you have no css class called "image":

```
$(this).closest('.image')
```

It should be (changed it to find, because it is a child element):

```
$(this).find('img')
```

Otherwise please share some details how is it not working. Any errors?

It is working after fixing all the things I wrote (so thanks for the minus):
http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/EdkHN/

Also you probably want to remove the whole span:
http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/EdkHN/1/

Comment: It is not working with remove of the image when clicked on the DELETE link....Not yet solved...

Comment: See update with jsfiddles

Comment: are the uploaded images seen as thumbnails?? i don't find such!!!

Comment: yes, they are (at least in FF 22.0). after you select an image it appears on the right side of the screen. With jQuery 1.10 it does not work in IE 10, so I changed it back to 1.9 and it is fine in IE 10 too: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/EdkHN/3/

Comment: that _delete_ link should also get deleted....but that remains even after the deletion of that particular image

Comment: Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/EdkHN/4/